c++ running multiple threads and return in main function once a thread throws
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>


class MyClass {
public:

    void run() {
        // do some work
    }
    struct Data {
        double x{0.0};
        int y{0};
    } data;
};

void Thread_function(int i, MyClass myclass, std::exception_ptr &exc, std::mutex &mtx)
{
    try {
        // Modify some of the struct parameters
        auto dataCopy = myclass.data;
        dataCopy.x = i + 1;
        dataCopy.y = (i + 1) * 0.5;
        // run the simulation with changed parameters
        myclass.data = dataCopy;
        myclass.run();
    } 
    catch (const std::exception &exception)
    {
        // lock capturedException
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        exc = std::current_exception();
    }
}

int main() {

    const int num_threads = 5;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::exception_ptr capturedException;
    std::mutex mtx;
    MyClass myClass;

    // create threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) 
    {
        threads.emplace_back(
            Thread_function, i, myClass, std::ref(capturedException), std::ref(mtx));
    }

    // wait for all threads to finish
    for (auto& t : threads) 
    {
        t.join();
    }

    // main thread rethrows exception, if any
    if (capturedException)
    {
        throw capturedException;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

Several threads are created in the main function which do some computations in the runfunction. In the thread function, I used try/catchblock to catch exceptions and std::lock_guard<std::mutex> for synchronization since excis a shared variable among all threads (passed by reference).
In the main function, I wait for all threads to join and then rethrow exception from the threads.
However, in main, I want to return 1 once a thread throwed an exception. No need to wait for the other threads then. At the moment, m̀ain waits for all threads to finish although one one of the threads possibly throwed an exception already.
How can I fix this? Are there classes in c++ library to handle this smoothly?

throw capturedException; return 1; will not return 1. Either rethrow the exception of return a value; you can't do both.

Minor point: there are three portable return value from main: EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS, and 0. Returning 0 indicates success, but EXIT_SUCCESS does not have to be 0. The effect of returning any other value is implementation- and OS-specific.

Add a HaveException atomic flag that the excepting thread can set and other threads can periodically test and exit if set. If your threads aren't in a loop where the exit flag can be tested, you have no safe way out.

Use std::async + std::future + lambda expression. Synchronizing with the future will rethrow the exception for you

@user4581301 How would you implement it "other threads can periodically test"? Can I do this in the main function?

First of all, you don't need to wait for threads to finish if you don't want to. So, you could just skip the joins and exit... except that this calls the thread destructors which will then cause problems because you haven't joined them. So, you could either isolate the vector from destruction entirely (allocate with new and don't delete it) -- or, instead of joining, you could instead detach the threads. You would still need some better handling around your exceptions, though...

For the "better handling of exceptions", I would probably make a counter for the active threads, an error flag, and a condition variable. When a thread exits it reduces the counter; when it exits with an error it sets the error flag (or the "captured exception", same thing). That way, your main thread knows exactly what's going on without being stuck in a join.

Note that I left the previous answer as an example; I've completely rewritten your code, and eliminated your MyClass since I don't know what it does anyway. In this example, the actual code goes into the MyThread::run function.'
It also gives a few more outputs.
The important thing is that we no longer wait for exceptions, since threads need to quit anyway. Instead, your run function needs to check the quit-condition frequently enough to suit your taste -- when one of the threads throws, the other threads will quit next time they call the performQuit function.
performQuit works by throwing an exception so it can be called from anywhere inside your stuff. This exception is caught and discarded, though.
A lot of changes are just me generally doing things differently than you.
Note that my example run runs for "thread number seconds", so they would normally quit every 1 second. This gets aborted when #3 throws its exception after 2.5 seconds.
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <list>
#include <chrono>

/************************************************************************/

class MyThread
{
private:
    static inline const std::chrono::time_point startTime=std::chrono::system_clock::now();

private:
    static inline std::mutex mutex;
    static inline std::exception_ptr capturedException;

private:
    class OperationCancelled { };

    static void performQuit()
    {
        std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);
        if (capturedException)
        {
            throw OperationCancelled();
        }
    }

    static void captureException()
    {
        // first exception "wins"; any other ones are lost since
        // we only have room for one.

        std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);
        if (!capturedException)
        {
            capturedException=std::current_exception();
        }
    }

public:
    static void rethrowIf()
    {
        if (capturedException)
        {
            std::rethrow_exception(capturedException);
        }
    }

private:
    std::thread thread;
    const int number;

private:
    void printStatus(std::string_view string)
    {
        auto elapsed=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()-startTime);

        std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);
        std::cout << elapsed.count() << "ms: thread " << number << " " << string << "\n";
    }

private:
    void run()
    {
        // We need to check the quit condition during the processing, so
        // for convenience reasons I'll pretend the actual job has a loop
        // so we can just check on each iteration. If it doesn't, add the
        // check in between work chunks or whatever -- the thread will
        // only quit on a check, so it's up to you how quickly the threads
        // will respond to a quit...

        for (int i=0; i<100*number; i++)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            performQuit();

            if (number==3 && i==250) throw std::runtime_error("boo!");
        }
    }

private:
    // this acts as a wrapper around the "run" function, so we keep
    // the clerical tasks separated from the actual function.
    void body()
    {
        printStatus("launched");
        try
        {
            run();
            printStatus("has completed task");
        }
        catch(const OperationCancelled&)
        {
            printStatus("was aborted");
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            printStatus("got exception");
            captureException();
        }
        printStatus("exit");
    }

public:
    MyThread(int number_)
        : number(number_)
    {
        thread=std::thread([this](){ body(); });
    }

    ~MyThread()
    {
        thread.join();
    }
};

/************************************************************************/

int main() {

    const int num_threads = 6;

    // create threads and wait for them to finish
    {
        std::list<MyThread> threads;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
        {
            threads.emplace_back(i);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        MyThread::rethrowIf();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& exception)
    {
        std::cerr << "exception: " << exception.what() << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The output:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp && ./a.out
0ms: thread 0 launched
0ms: thread 0 has completed task
0ms: thread 0 exit
0ms: thread 1 launched
0ms: thread 2 launched
0ms: thread 3 launched
0ms: thread 4 launched
0ms: thread 5 launched
1007ms: thread 1 has completed task
1007ms: thread 1 exit
2014ms: thread 2 has completed task
2014ms: thread 2 exit
2528ms: thread 3 got exception
2528ms: thread 3 exit
2538ms: thread 4 was aborted
2538ms: thread 4 exit
2538ms: thread 5 was aborted
2538ms: thread 5 exit
exception: boo!


For completeness, can you also add your previous answer (using .detach())?

Let me sketch you an example of an alternative piece of code:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cassert>

class MyClass {
public:

    void run() {
        // do some work
    }
    struct Data {
        double x{0.0};
        int y{0};
    } data;
};

void Thread_function(int i, MyClass myclass)
{
    if (i==3)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(i));
        throw std::runtime_error("boo!");
    }

    // Modify some of the struct parameters
    auto dataCopy = myclass.data;
    dataCopy.x = i + 1;
    dataCopy.y = (i + 1) * 0.5;

    // run the simulation with changed parameters
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(i*2));

    myclass.data = dataCopy;
    myclass.run();
}

int main() {

    const int num_threads = 5;
    MyClass myClass;

    struct Tracking
    {
        std::mutex mutex;
        std::condition_variable condition;
        unsigned int counter=0;
        std::exception_ptr capturedException;
    };
    static Tracking& tracking=*new Tracking;

    // create threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<decltype(tracking.mutex)> lock(tracking.mutex);
            tracking.counter++;
        }
        std::thread([i](){
            try
            {
                Thread_function(i, MyClass());
            }
            catch(const std::exception &exception)
            {
                std::lock_guard<decltype(tracking.mutex)> lock(tracking.mutex);
                std::cout << "thread " << i << " exception\n";
                if (!tracking.capturedException)
                {
                    tracking.capturedException=std::current_exception();
                }
            }
            {
                std::lock_guard<decltype(tracking.mutex)> lock(tracking.mutex);
                tracking.counter--;
                std::cout << "thread " << i << " exit\n";
            }
            tracking.condition.notify_all();
        }).detach();
    }

    // wait for all threads to finish, or an exception to appear
    std::unique_lock<decltype(tracking.mutex)> lock(tracking.mutex);
    tracking.condition.wait(lock, [](){
        std::cout << "waiting for " << tracking.counter << " remaining threads\n";
        return tracking.counter==0 || tracking.capturedException;
    });

    // main thread rethrows exception, if any
    if (tracking.capturedException)
    {
        try
        {
             std::rethrow_exception(tracking.capturedException);
        }
        catch(const std::exception& exception)
        {
            std::cerr << exception.what() << "\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    assert(tracking.counter==0);
    return 0;
}

This will output:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp && ./a.out
thread 0 exit
waiting for 4 remaining threads
thread 1 exit
waiting for 3 remaining threads
thread 3 exception
thread 3 exit
waiting for 2 remaining threads
boo!

I mostly stuck with your structure, but let me point out some changes.
When creating the threads, I put a wrapper around your Thread_Function that handles communication with the main thread. The main threads counts how many threads it creates, while the wrapper code reduces the count when threads exit. A condition variable is used to tell the main thread that something has changed.
I've removed the vector and joins, since I don't need those. Things are likely different if the threads need a clean exit, like because they write files or something. This would change the whole setup, though, and also requires that "Thread_Function" would regularly check for a quit condition (like if it runs a loop, it could check that on each iteration) -- you cannot just "interrupt" a thread from the outside.
Also note that you've passed copies of your "MyClass" around, so I removed that too and just gave every Thread_Function a new object. If you intended to pass a reference around... my bad.
The sleeps are just there for the threads to simulate some work.
The main thread waits for either the count to reach 0, or an exception to show up.
Also, different from your code, I'm just printing the exception on the main thread. No point rethrowing it there.
Why did I make the tracking static like that?

Each thread does intensive computations and writes some data to disk. I would prefer a solution using join rather than detach, because, once main returns, I have to be certain that all threads are finished (either terminated or successfully return from the run member function). Can you adjust your solution using join instead of detach?
